# Android - handle fragment onClick from activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment class, that contains some field.

```
public class ReviewFragment extends Fragment {

    //...
    private String paramText;
    public String getParamText() { return paramText; }
    //...
}
```

From activity I add several instances of this fragment, and set this field value. Also I put each instance in List and set fragment tag = "fragment0", "fragment1" etc.

```
public class ReviewActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private List<ReviewFragment> reviewFragments = new ArrayList<>();

    //...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          //...

          int i = 0;
          for (Comment comment : comments) {
                ReviewFragment reviewFragment = ReviewFragment.newInstance(comment.getAuthor(), comment.getText(), comment.getRate());
                reviewFragments.add(reviewFragment);
                transaction.add(ll.getId(), reviewFragment, "review" + i);
                i++;
          }
    }
```

I need to handle the click on the each instance of ReviewFragment instance. So in Android Studio designer I attach the following method to onClick of the root layout of ReviewFragment.

```
    public void reviewClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FullReviewActivity.class);
        String fragmentTag = view.getTag().toString();
        //...
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

I'm trying to get fragment tag to find the fragment in my reviewFragments List. The problem is that view.getTag() return null, not the "reviewN". I tried to write the same method in ReviewFragment class, but Android Studio didn't allow me to attach it to onClick.

So problem is - in onClick handle method I need to get both activity and fragment. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you need to have a bunch of `Fragments`. Maybe in this case it is better to use `ListView` (or any other type of it, for example `RecyclerView`). You can easily listen for click event and do whatever you want having number of list item.

If you really need to use Fragments. You can follow different ways.
Firstly in your  `reviewClick(View view)` you are getting not fragment tag, but view tag. Why you are having `View` as an argument ?
You can follow most common used approach in case you need fragments use callback method in your `Activity`.
The problem here that your `Framgent` may contain different views and you cannot get onClick directly on whole fragment, if you are not using overlay layout, but in this case you also have to handle layout onclick event.
Possible solution as I have already mentioned is to use callback method.

Here are several steps to implement this :

Create inner interface in your fragment,for example

```
 public interface       OnReviewSelectedListener {
        public void onReviewSelected(int position);  }
```

Your activtiy now have to implement this interface

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements ReviewFragment.OnReviewSelectedListener
```

You can determine framgent in

```
 public void onReviewSelected(int position) {
          if(position==YOUR_TAG) {

          }
    }
```

And in `ReviewFragment` in `onAttach` method you have to cast activity to your interface.

```
   @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnReviewSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnReviewSelectedListener");
        }
    }
```

And if you really wanna to use fragment with tags you can do following in your fragment.

```
public void onCommentClick() {
      // do some stuff
     mCallback.onReviewSelected(getFramgentTag());
}
```

Comment: It's possible to use Fragment as argument? Didn't know, I will try it now.
Can you please give a code sample for second option?

Comment: It would be better if you could provide full code of your activity and fragment.

Comment: As I can quess you want to implement comments/reviews and on click do something with this comment ?

Comment: I couldn't attach method with Fragment argument to onClick, there is a runtime exception.
Android studio generates something like the code you provide, yes, I think it's what I need, I will try this way. 
It's a very bad code, I think you will be sad when looking at it :(
Yes, I already implement short comments and I want to show another activity with full text of comment when user clicking on the short version.

Comment: I have edited my post, please have a look.   If you have any questions please feel free to ask.

Comment: You are welcome, if you have some other questions, please feel free to ask. But it will better to post new question than in order to avoid "comment discussions"