# Is it possible to implement separate buttons onclickListener in both Activity and Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

My MainActivity contain buttons which is used to switch to different fragments. Inside each fragment there are also has buttons. Activity button onClickListener work fine before implementing button onClickListener in fragments. I wonder if this is not supported by Android or my code is not correct.
Any pointer is appreciated. Thank you.

Fragment code:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    v = inflater.inflate(fragment1, container, false);

    b2=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v){
            button2Clicked(v);
        }
    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
 }
public void button2Clicked(View view){
   //do something
 }
```

Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private Button btnHealth;
private Button btnSetting;
private Button btnSleep;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Init component
    btnHealth = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHealth);
    btnSleep = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSleep);
    btnSetting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSetting);

    replaceFragment(1);

    btnHealth.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        //On click function
        public void onClick(View view) {
            replaceFragment(0);
        }
    });

    btnSleep.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        //On click function
        public void onClick(View view) {
            replaceFragment(1);
        }
    });

    btnSetting.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        //On click function
        public void onClick(View view) {
            replaceFragment(2);
        }
    });

}


//Create method replace fragment

private void replaceFragment(int pos) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (pos) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Fragment1();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Fragment3();
            break;
        default:
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            break;
    }

    if(null!=fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}


}
```

Comment: please give reason for down vote.

Comment: why are you returning `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);` not that `View v`?

Comment: Don't set another listener in the Fragment, just call fragment button2Clicked() from the Activity when the button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. If you want to handle the OnClick Event of the fragment inside the Activity class, you can do so by using FragmentInteractionListener (interface). Example: [Android - handle fragment onClick from activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148195/android-handle-fragment-onclick-from-activity)